# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch. has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

I am the following error

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ProposalsController#create

User(#78682120) expected, got String(#68929150)
Rails.root: /home/james/app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/proposals_controller.rb:76:in `new'
app/controllers/proposals_controller.rb:76:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"0qTzQ/KMA2Ch60aajSg265tThfCTBCB7w0rS8nD4Qwg=",
 "proposal"=>{"phones"=>"",
 "broadband"=>"",
 "fixed_line"=>"",
 "group_calling"=>"",
 "frequent_txt"=>"",
 "frequent_data"=>"",
 "type"=>"TelecommunicationsProposal",
 "contact_type"=>"",
 "extra_options"=>"",
 "current_provider"=>"",
 "closing_date"=>"03/12/2012",
 "users"=>["#<User:0x961c9e4>"]},
 "commit"=>"Create Proposal"}
```

I am trying to have a relationship such that a user has many proposals, and the proposal can have many users.

I have it that I can get the proposals for each user, but need it to be the other way around also.

Proposal.rb

```
 class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :users
    ...
```

TelcommunicationsProposal.rb

```
class TelecommunicationsProposal < Proposal
  belongs_to :users
  after_create :proposal_creation
  ...
```

ProposalsController.rb
Error breaks on line 76 which is the Proposal.new creation

```
 def create
    @proposal = Proposal.new(params[:proposal])

    if current_user
     @user = current_user
```

Small excerpt from app/views/telecommunications_proposal/_form.html.erb

```
 <% for user in User.find(:all) %>  
    <div>  
      <%= check_box_tag "proposal[users][]",user%>  
      <%= user.trading_name %>  
    </div>  
<% end %>
```

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you should be passing the `id` of the user to `check_box_tag`, not the record itself, and use `user_ids` in the name of the checkboxes rather than `users`:

```
<%= check_box_tag "proposal[user_ids][]", user.id %>
```

Refs:

- [HABTM Checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast)
- [Methods Added by has_many](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many)